# Restrict Component Visibility in Lightning App Builder

Tags: visibility, lightning-app-builder

This is probably a very simple question but I'm struggling to understand one little detail. I went through loads of different tutorials but didn't find the answer.

On my Account page, I need to limit a component visibility to a specific permission set through the Lightning App Builder. I click the component - Set Visibility - Add Filter - Advanced - Select - Permissions - then there is an option to choose between the Standard and Custom Permissions.

None of these two include the permission set I need. In fact none of the permissions looks like my permission sets.

What are these permissions? And how can I limit a specific component (Engagement History Dashboard) to a specific permission set?

[image: Restrict Visibility]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find permission set in dynamic form. What you need to do is create a [custom permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5) from setup and assign that to the permission set you created. Now select that custom permission here and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It helped me massively.
One more question regarding custom permissions. On my permission set there seems to be no option to add custom permissions. I went through different types of permission sets and some of them have Custom Permissions under Apps, others don't. Can I still add my set in any way?

Comment: Happy to help. Keep coding

Comment: There is seperate option of custom permission in every permission set.There might be some user access missing. Follow this link for more insight https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_sets_custom_perms.htm&type=5